# Cut Out Text Effect In Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

How Can I do a text cut into a box container that leaves the content under it seen?

Here's exactly what I mean:
[image]

As you can see **the immage is seen under the text**. How could I do this?

Comment: see https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use `CustomPainter`, `TextPainter`, `BlendMode` and `saveLayer`:

[image: result]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Playground',
      home: TestPage(),
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/3g.jpg'), fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: CutOutTextPainter(text: 'YOUR NAME'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CutOutTextPainter extends CustomPainter {
  CutOutTextPainter({required this.text}) {
    _textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: text,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 40.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        ),
      ),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );
    _textPainter.layout();
  }

  final String text;
  late final TextPainter _textPainter;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Draw the text in the middle of the canvas
    final textOffset =
        size.center(Offset.zero) - _textPainter.size.center(Offset.zero);
    final textRect = textOffset & _textPainter.size;

    // The box surrounding the text should be 10 pixels larger, with 4 pixels corner radius
    final boxRect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        textRect.inflate(10.0), const Radius.circular(4.0));
    final boxPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..blendMode = BlendMode.srcOut;

    canvas.saveLayer(boxRect.outerRect, Paint());

    _textPainter.paint(canvas, textOffset);
    canvas.drawRRect(boxRect, boxPaint);

    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CutOutTextPainter oldDelegate) {
    return text != oldDelegate.text;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think a more general purpose rendering could be achieved by blending 2 RepaintBoundary into one. Not sure about the performances impact though

Comment: Maybe, but I think this good enough as an answer. Easy enough to be understood

Answer (score 11):

You could use a [ShaderMask](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ShaderMask-class.html) for that, which allows you to apply a shader to a widget, taking a [Blend Mode](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode-class.html) into account. The Blend Mode is what we're interested in, so the Shader will be a simple color:

```
class Cutout extends StatelessWidget {
  const Cutout({
    Key key,
    @required this.color,
    @required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Color color;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShaderMask(
      blendMode: BlendMode.srcOut,
      shaderCallback: (bounds) => LinearGradient(colors: [color], stops: [0.0]).createShader(bounds),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Here is an example render:
[image: Render of the Cutout widget]

For your exact example image, the child should be a `Text` widget and you should also include this in a `ClipRRect` for the rounded corners (or you can figure out more optimal solutions using `BoxDecoration` if the performance impact of `ClipRRect` is an issue)

The advantage of this solution is that it works with any widget as a child and that it's a composable widget that you can pop in your layout.

Comment: I should also mention that the black part of the render can either be a [Gradient](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Gradient-class.html) or [ImageShader](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/ImageShader-class.html) and that in my example, I am using a Gradient to simulate a simple color. As far as I know, these 2 [shaders](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Shader-class.html) are the only ones available by default in Flutter. Both could be used for some interesting results.