# Cut Out Text Effect In Flutter + Padding

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement `some Cut Out Text Effect` as indicated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55570169/8096916.

It works well until I want to add a `Vertical padding` to the text.

[image: Imgur]

**NORMAL:**

```
ShaderMask(
      blendMode: BlendMode.srcOut,
      shaderCallback: (bounds) =>
          LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.white], stops: [0.0]).createShader(bounds),
      child: Text('Example'),
);
```

**WITH HORIZONTAL PADDING:**

```
ShaderMask(
      blendMode: BlendMode.srcOut,
      shaderCallback: (bounds) =>
          LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.white], stops: [0.0]).createShader(bounds),
      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                          child: 
Text('Example'),
),);
```

**WITH VERTICAL PADDING**

```
ShaderMask(
      blendMode: BlendMode.srcOut,
      shaderCallback: (bounds) =>
          LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.white], stops: [0.0]).createShader(bounds),
      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                          child: 
Text('Example'),
),);
```

I also tried give a height in the TextStyle but has the same effect as the vertical padding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Container instead of a Padding to fix it, try the next:

```
ShaderMask(
      blendMode: BlendMode.srcOut,
      shaderCallback: (bounds) =>
          LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.white], stops: [0.0]).createShader(bounds),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
        child: Text('Example'),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: It doesn't work. the shader mask i think is only applied to the Text frame,  adding horizontal padding makes the text widget to expand but the vertical padding or setting the height of the Text Widget in the TextStyle doesn't work